# yii custom dropdown are blank out after validation

Tags: php, yii

status : I've 3 depended dropdown custom filed validation at user/create. They are validating fine.
Q : after submitting, if there are not passing the validating, all of my dropdown lists are blank out. how can I do?

This is before submitting
[image: before submitting]

This is after submitting 
[image: After submitting]

this is department tbl structure

```
department
id | name      | p_id | company_id
1  | dep1      | 0    | 1
2  | dep2      | 0    | 1
3  | sec1.1    | 1    | 1
4  | sec2.1    | 2    | 1
5  | team1.1.1 | 3    | 1
6  | team1.1.2 | 3    | 1
7  | team2.1.1 | 4    | 1
```

This is user tbl structure

```
user
id | name | company_id | team_id
```

team_id relationship with department tbl.

this is rule at user model

```
public $section;
    public $team;
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('login_name, email, rank_id, company_id, team_id, section, team', 'required'), // team_id is Department   
            array('rank_id, company_id, team_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('login_name, first_name, last_name', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('password', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('email', 'length', 'max'=>200),

            array('password', 'compare', 'on' => 'create'),
            array('password_repeat', 'safe', 'on' => 'create'),
            array('password, password_repeat', 'required', 'on' => 'create'),

            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('first_name, last_name, email, created, updated, rank_id, company_id, team_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

This view (_form.php)

```
<!-- This is Department -->
<div class="row">
        <?php
            if($model->company_id)
            {
                $records = Department::model()->findAll('p_id=0 AND company_id=:company_id', array(':company_id'=>(int) $model->company_id));
                $department_list = CHtml::listData($records, 'id', 'name');
            }else $department_list = array();
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'team_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'team_id', $department_list, array('prompt'=>'Please select a department',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type'=>'POST', //request type
                    'url'=>CController::createUrl('user/dynamicsection'), //url to call.
                    'dataType'=>'json',
                    'data'=>array('department_id'=>'js:this.value'),  
                    'success'=>'function(data) {
                        $("#User_section").html(data.ddsection);
                        $("#User_team").html(data.ddteam);
                    }',
                )
            )
        ); 
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'team_id'); ?>
    </div>
<!-- This is section -->
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'section'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'section', array(), array('prompt'=>'Please select a section',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST', //request type
            'url'=>CController::createUrl('user/dynamicteam'), //url to call.
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'data'=>array('section'=>'js:this.value'),  
            'success'=>'function(data) {
                        $("#User_team").html(data.ddteam);
                    }',
        ))); ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model,'section'); ?>


    </div>
<!-- This is Team -->
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'team'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'team', array(), array('prompt'=>'Please select a team')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'team'); ?>


    </div>
```

This Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new User;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
            if(User::model()->exists("login_name='".$_POST['User']['login_name']."'"))
            {
                $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['User'];

                $duplicate_error = '<p>Please fix the following input errors:</p>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Name is duplicated.</li>
                    </ul>';
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('duplicate_error',$duplicate_error);
                $this->redirect(array('user/create'));
            }else{
                $currentTime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());             
                $model->created = $currentTime;

                $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];

                if($_POST['User']['team']){
                    $model->team_id = (int)$_POST['User']['team'];
                    $dep['team'] = (int)$_POST['User']['team'];

                }elseif($_POST['User']['section']){
                    $model->team_id = (int)$_POST['User']['section'];
                    $dep['section'] = (int)$_POST['User']['section'];

                }elseif($_POST['User']['team_id']){
                    $model->team_id = (int)$_POST['User']['team_id'];
                    $dep['department'] = (int)$_POST['User']['team_id'];
                }
                if($model->save())
                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));

            }
        }



        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Thank for your help.

========**********=========

updated model did not change,

view add

'options'=>array("$model->section"=>array('selected'=>'selected')),

into dorpdown

controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new User;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
            if(User::model()->exists("login_name='".$_POST['User']['login_name']."'"))
            {
                $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['User'];

                $duplicate_error = '<p>Please fix the following input errors:</p>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Name is duplicated.</li>
                    </ul>';
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('duplicate_error',$duplicate_error);
                $this->redirect(array('user/create'));
            }else{
                $currentTime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());             
                $model->created = $currentTime;

                $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                $model->team = (int)$_POST['User']['team'];
                $model->section = (int)$_POST['User']['section'];


                if($_POST['User']['team']){
                    $model->team_id = (int)$_POST['User']['team'];              
                }elseif($_POST['User']['section']){
                    $model->team_id = (int)$_POST['User']['section'];               
                }elseif($_POST['User']['team_id']){
                    $model->team_id = (int)$_POST['User']['team_id'];
                }


                if($model->save())
                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));

            }
        }

        //$dst = $this->getDST($model->team_id);

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'department'=>0,
            'section'=>0,
            'team'=>0,
        ));
    }
```

dropdown blank out problem is gone away. but not validate section and team. How can I?

Comment: first notice, `User::model()->exists` is wrong at this point, please look into the [CUniqueValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator)  and use in the model.

Comment: second notice, I don't see see any rank_id, company_id, team_id in the safe list for this scenario so that is probably your cause.

Comment: can you explain more detail? bec I've <1 month experience of yii.

Comment: check understanding safe validation rules in google.

Comment: I read safe validation. and update my last situation. pls help me.

Comment: why would you like to save drop down settings that didn't passed validation?

Comment: @Jeffrey, you know, all of the user don't want to re-enter when they make a small mistake (included me).

Answer (score 0):

The validation rule to compare password is missing a parameter for the compareAttribute:

```
array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password_repeat', 'on'=>'create'),
```

HTH

Comment: @nwd, when I replaced your rule into my password compare rule, the validation is working at update form. how can solve?

Comment: @tharsoe I'm not sure I understand the question or problem.

Comment: @nwd, password compare rule should be working at user creation form only. but when I add your rule to my model rule function, the password field validation is working at update form after removing the password and password_repeated field.

Comment: @tharsoe the 'on' => 'create' part of the above array should only enforce that validation when the scenario is 'create'. To set the scenario you would use `$model = new User( 'create' );` or once you have retrieved a user `$model->setScenario( 'create' );`

Comment: Yes. I've done yesterday night this problem with Scenario. thx for your help.